# Finding out which process inhibits monitor sleep, even after setting DPMS flags

Tags: xorg, dpms

My screens aren't turning off, using xset to set dpms off, suspend or standby they always turn on again. I know a way to figure out what event caused the system to wake up from suspend, but I haven't found something like that for dpms events.

After a restart they behave again, which led me to blame some specific process that I don't usually do. I started manually quitting processes until I found steam to be the most likely culprit (there's a [bug report about this issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5607)), but I could do without going one by one. Is there a event/log about which process/event causes monitors to break dpms state?

Comment: I was going to ask "do you run any steam games?" and then I saw you mentioned steam.   I've found that **some** (but far from all) games in steam will disable screen blanking and fail to re-enable it, even after the game has exited cleanly.   It's not steam itself, it's some of the games.  I've found the only way to "fix" that is to go into my xfce4 Screensaver settings and de-active the screensaver and immediately re-activate it.  Then do the same for Display Power Management in the xfce4 Power Manager.

Comment: BTW, media players like `smplayer` or `mpv` can be configured to disable screen blanking (and often are by default) while they're playing a video.  They're usually well-behaved enough to re-enable it once they've quit.

Comment: @cas no, it's literally steam. I close it, dpms starts working, open steam without opening a game, dpms stops. [There's a bug report about the behavior](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5607). Steam at least is consistent in cleaning after itself when closing.

Comment: That's odd.  I can leave steam running for literally weeks or months at a time (I rarely reboot) and it doesn't affect my screen saver at all.   Run some particular games, and it gets disabled - which, of course, I only notice hours later, about 20 minutes after I've gone to bed and am wondering "did I forget to turn off the light in my computer room?"

Comment: @cas it's not the screen saver, it's the DPMS off behavior where the monitor go to a lower energy level without needing to logoff.